# Custom key value pairs on app/web/config/settings with WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, web-config, settings, app-config

Ok, this is an easy one I think.

I need to get from configuration several key value pairs on a WCF Service Application.

- Which file could be used?
  *app.config/web.config/settings.settings/etc*
- Which would be the best for a WCF (in VS2010 at least)? Why?
- How to write it on the config file? (e.g. `<sometag><add
  key="foo">bar</add></sometag>`)
- How to call it from the codebehind in the project? `ConfigurationManager["foo"].Something`?

I guess with this I'm clearly showing my confusion with each of those files.

I hope someone can dissipate the fog!

Answer (score 4):

You should have an app.config file in your VS project. If you don't, you can add one to the project by right clicking the project within the Solution Explorer, then Add, then New Item. From the "Add New Item" screen, you should see "general" among the common items on the left. Double click the first item "Application Configuration File" in the middle screen and you should be good to go.

From there, you can add your XML tags.

Typical Format in the app.config looks like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <configuration>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
    </startup>
    <appSettings>
       <add key="HostDomain" value="\\somedatabaseserver\DatabaseUnitTests" />
       <add key="Port" value="" />
     </appSettings>
 </configuration>
```

Depending on how you compile your WCF service (which format), you should get witin your \project\bin\debug directory a .config file with the same name as your executable or DLL.

Reading the config file in code is done with something like this:

```
  Dim confReader As System.Configuration.AppSettingsReader = New System.Configuration.AppSettingsReader
  sHostDomain = confReader.GetValue("HostDomain", GetType(System.String)).ToString()
  sPort = confReader.GetValue("Port", GetType(System.String)).ToString()
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: As oddly as it seems, VS2010 does not show as an option to add an app.config to the WCF Application, Listed as options I only have web.config, app.manifest... I could create one out of nowhere but, I think VS is trying to tell me something by removing the option.

Comment: And even when I can create the app.config on a class project referenced to the WCF (which only appears with the `<configuration></configuration>` tag, It still does not let me to do this `confReader.GetValue("HostDomain", GetType(System.String)).ToString()` (FYI that tag has actually  been afterwards created under appSettings).

Comment: Sorry, I'm getting back to you late. I work in europe and leave at 5. Web.config will also work. Depending on how you deploy your project, web.config works the same as app.config.